# facebook api hide comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm trying to hide a comment in a post in my page, i've tried:

```
curl -X "POST" -k "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/[comment_id]/?access_token=[access_token]&is_hidden=true"
```

as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/comment), i am getting this response:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#210) Updating is_hidden requires a Page access token","type":"OAuthException","code":210}}
```

also i tried sending the parameters using `--data` in curl but it didn't work too

## Edit:

Note: the token is a page access token

Comment: unfortunately its a page access token.

Comment: Do you know what permissions are on the token?

Comment: @nthall I've tested with a full permission page token.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
curl -XPOST \
     -k \
     -F 'is_hidden=true' \
     -F 'access_token=[access_token]' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/[comment_id]
```

Also, check your access token to comply to

> **Permissions**
>
> - A user access token with publish_actions permission is required to edit a comment posted by that user.
> - A page access token with publish_pages permission is required to edit a comment posted by that Page.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/comment#updating

Comment: For testing i've generated a page access token with full permission, same error:
`{"error":{"message":"(#210) Updating is_hidden requires a Page access token","type":"OAuthException","code":210}}`

Comment: Have you checked it here? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Yes, it tell me that it's valid and it have these scopes `user_birthday, user_reli...tory, user_work_history, user_website, user_managed_groups, user_events, user_photos, user_videos, user_friends, user_about_me, user_status, user_games_activity, user_tagged_places, user_posts, read_page_mailboxes, rsvp_event, email, ads_management, ads_read, read_insights, manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions, read_audience_network_insights, read_custom_friendlists, user_actions.video, user_actions.news, user_actions.books, user_actions.music, user_actions.fitness, public_profile`

Comment: Does the debug tool output list the specific page as well? If not, then it is _not_ a page access token … (which it doesn’t seem to be from what the error message says already.)