# cURL request in .NET to hide a comment in Facebook page

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I read in this answer: [facebook api hide comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32610992/1484184) that you can hide a Facebook comment using this cURL request:

```
curl -XPOST \
     -k \
     -F 'is_hidden=true' \
     -F 'access_token=[access_token]' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/[comment_id]
```

How can I make that request in C#?

Please give a clear working code.

Comment: It's just POST request with is_hidden=true&access_token=[access_token] in body, you can find a lot of information over internet about how to make POST requests in .NET, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/5311735

Answer (score 1):

I think the -F flag means it is part of a multipart form: https://ec.haxx.se/http-multipart.html

This may not necessarily work but it should give an idea:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var content =
                new MultipartFormDataContent("upload----" + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent("true"), "is_hidden");
                content.Add(new StringContent("[access_token]"), "access_token");

                var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/[comment_id]"), 
                                               content).Result; // You could use await here

            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't get it, i believe it is too much asked if i tell you to write me the all code, thank you for you answer anyway, very kind you.

Comment: as soon as somebody mark it as close to the answer, i will check it as an answer.